# "Определены задачи – завершить... и выйти на..." Двоеточие или тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире-или-двоеточие

Что лучше поставить в этом предложении, двоеточие или тире?

"Были определены задачи – завершить монтаж и пуско-наладку оборудования технологической линии по производству шаровых кранов Ду 700 – Ду 1200 и выйти на серийное производство шаровых кранов всех типоразмеров диаметром от Ду 10 до Ду 1200 мм".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше поставить тире: "Были определены задачи -  завершить монтаж и пуско-наладку оборудования технологической линии по производству шаровых кранов Ду 700 – Ду 1200 и выйти на серийное производство шаровых кранов всех типоразмеров диаметром от Ду 10 до Ду 1200 мм".

Пояснение

Это обособленное несогласованное определение, выраженное инфинитивом. Такие определения или не обособляются вообще, или обособляются с помощью тире. Обособление связано со значительной распространенностью определения, а также плохой сочетаемостью выражения "задача завершить монтаж".

ПРИМЕРЫ НЕОБОСОБЛЕННЫХ И ОБОСОБЛЕННЫХ ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЙ

Он послал адъютанта с приказанием  атаковать французов. Надо иметь мужество признать свою неудачу.

Но прекрасен данный жребий – просиять и умереть. Мы все были одержимы одной страстью – сопротивляться. У человека есть одна обязанность – творить. Сбылась его давняя мечта – уехать в город.

Answer (score 0):

В этом предложении можно не ставить никакого знака после слова "задачи", так как инфинитивами выражены несогласованные определения (определены задачи какие? завершить...и выйти на производство)

Answer (score 0):

Возможны оба варианта. См.: Справочник-практикум .Факультативные знаки препинания.Стр.336.Д.Э. Розенталь.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, следует поставить двоеточие (т.к. далее раскрывается, какие именно задачи) и пусконаладка пишем слитно. Кроме того, характеристики кранов разделяем не тире, а дефисом.

Были определены задачи: завершить монтаж и пусконаладку оборудования технологической линии по производству шаровых кранов Ду 700–Ду 1200 и выйти на серийное производство шаровых кранов всех типоразмеров диаметром от Ду 10 до Ду 1200 мм.

Comment: Возможно, здесь два варианта с разными решениями: 1)Была определена задача - завершить монтаж  и выйти на серийное производство (несогласованное определение). 2) "Были определены задачи: завершить монтаж и выйти на серийное производство (обобщающее слово).

Comment: София, с вами спорить не могу, т.к. Ваши знания просто потрясают!

А не организовать ли инам Общество ревнителей русского языка?
Страшно газеты открывать и ТВ включать.